# How to create a single series bar graph with Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to create a simple Highcharts bar graph with a single series and multiple labels in the legend. How is this done?

Here is an example:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: true,
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        labelFormatter: function() {
            return this.name + " - <span class='total'>"+this.y+"</span>"
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Simple Bar Graph'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['First', 'Second', 'Third', 'Fourth', , 'Fifth'],
        allowDecimals: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false
    },

    series: [
        {
            data: [
                {y: 6, name: 'First', color: 'blue'},
                {y: 7, name: 'Second', color: 'green'},
                {y: 9, name: 'Third', color: 'yellow'},
                {y: 1, name: 'Fourth', color: 'orange'},
                {y: 1, name: 'Fifth', color: 'red'}
            ]
        }
    ],

});
```

Comment: jsfiddle is no longer available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, Highcharts is pretty flexible.
We can do some tricks (maybe hacks?) to achieve this kind of "non-convential" tasks.

What you could do in your case is create "fake" serieses, and use custom event handlers:

```
    series: [
        {
            pointWidth:20,
            color: colors[0],
            showInLegend:false,
            data: [
                {y: 6, name: 'First', color: colors[0]},
                {y: 7, name: 'Second', color: colors[1]},
                {y: 9, name: 'Third', color: colors[2]},
                {y: 1, name: 'Fourth', color: colors[3]},
                {y: 1, name: 'Fifth', color: colors[4]}
            ]
        },
        {color: 'blue'},
        {color: 'green'},
        {color: 'yellow'},
        {color: 'orange'},
        {color: 'red'}

    ],
```

In order to format the legend labels we can use `labelFormatter` for the legend:

```
    legend: {
        labelFormatter: function(){
            return names[this.index-1];
        }
    },
```

this will set the legend label to the name of the corresponding point.

And finally we need to handle the legend click, to imitate the "normal" behaviour:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            events: {
                legendItemClick: function (x) {
                    var i = this.index  - 1;
                    var series = this.chart.series[0];
                    var point = series.points[i];   

                    if(point.oldY == undefined)
                       point.oldY = point.y;

                    point.update({y: point.y != null ? null : point.oldY});
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

These are just examples, you can **obviously** improve this and adjust to your own need.

Good Luck!

http://jsfiddle.net/otm0oq2c/3/

Comment: Thanks @MorKadosh. But why do you say this is unconventional. It seems like this would be the most basic way to show this data. Do you feel there a better way to show data that looks like the above?

Comment: The reason I said that is because this functionallity is not coming "out of the box", but there's nothing bad about doing this, that's why their API is pretty flexible.

Comment: Oh geez, you have to go through all that to make a simple bar graph?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way than the accepted answer is by setting the `categories` key as an array of 'labels' and the `series.data` as an array of 'values'.

Here is an example that uses a collection (Array of objects) or a flat object to populate a bar chart in Highcharts ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9862307r/5/)):

The example assumes a an array of objects with keys name/value, or a simple object of key/value:

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Simple Bar'
    },

    chart: {type: 'bar'},

     xAxis: {
     // categories: Object.keys(obj)
     // or
        categories: collection.map(i => i.name)
    }, 

        series: [{
        name: 'Usage',
        colorByPoint: true,
     // data: Object.values(obj)
     // or:
        data: collection.map(i => i.value)
    }],
    legend: false
});
```