# Highcharts creating simple horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bar-chart

I am trying to make a simple highcharts bar chart, different than this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bar-stacked/), where I just need categories on x axis and values on y axis, with a bar for each category, without them being stacked. So basically what I am talking about is having for example categories bananas, apples, oranges, and for each of the categories number of items, 100 bananas, 50, apples, and so on, without further categorization on people, like in the example shown. I am trying and going through there documentation to see how to set up the options for that kind of setup, but I am not getting anywhere, so was just wondering if anyone knows how to set it up.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Stacked bar chart'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumption'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: null
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Joe',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});
```

});

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a single series bar graph with Highcharts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041311/how-to-create-a-single-series-bar-graph-with-highcharts)

Comment: Try `series: [{ name: 'Amount', data: [50, 100, 75, 25, 50] }]`