# Controlling columns with legends of simple series column chart of Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

*(Might be a possible duplicate of [How to create a single series bar graph with Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041311/how-to-create-a-single-series-bar-graph-with-highcharts))*

I'm trying to create a simple Highcharts column chart with a single series and multiple labels in the legend as shown below

[image: UI for series bar chart]

By toggling the legend( Series 1 ) it shows and hides **both column charts**.I need to control the individual column with the legends (which should be labelled Jan and Feb )

The code snippet for reference -

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb' ]
        
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    
    series: [
        {
            data: [
                {y: 6, name: 'First', color: 'blue'},
                {y: 6, name: 'sec', color: 'red'}
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Could you specify what the problem is? This does indeed look like a duplicate for the question you have referenced. Did you already implement the answer from that question?

Comment: @ewolden I am trying to implement it without using much JS, the problem as I've mentioned here ; there should be 2 legends i.e Jan, Feb. Further, on clicking on the legend (say Jan) it should hide only the Jan column chart(and also the x-axis label obviously)

Comment: Well, I doubt you can simplify it much more than in the answer you already found. The reason for this is that you are trying to use highcharts in a way that it was not intended. The other alternative is create a series for each point, and set the rest to `null` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/md2zk/110

Comment: There's even a simper version (without nulls) of the approach proposed by @ewolden: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y6owkx2h/